# -notlike $array not functioning

Tags: powershell

I want to delete all users except some that I want to keep

However it seems that using `notlike` with an array doesn't work except when it has one entry?

Using Remove Item and item names is not a valid workaround.
I think I will need to make a loop that checks what is being piped for each Dir in Udirs.

Which I know how to word in English but not in PowerShell.

I have no clue how to do that.

```
$computer = (Read-Host "Enter Computer name")
$UDirs = @()
do {
  $input = (Read-Host "Enter Username")
  if ($input -ne '') {$UDirs +=  "\\$computer\c$\Users\$input*"}
}
until ($input -eq '')

$UDirs

Get-ChildItem -Path  "\\$computer\c$\Users\" -Recurse |
    Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\Users\ntanghe'} |
    Where {$_ -notlike "$UDirs"} |
    sort length -Descending #|
    #Remove-Item -force
```

Comment: See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d99062ac-37fd-43e1-982b-5808051475b1/powershell-using-notcontains-notlike-and-notmatch-for-multiple-items?forum=ITCG and http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex.aspx

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Your code is poorly formatted and hard to read imho.

Comment: Code only needed a minor formatting update to fix the line spacing and indenting.

Comment: Small note to OP, instead of commenting out code for testing (`Remove-Item` in your code), a lot of commands support the `-WhatIf` parameter. Using this means the command only informs you what it would do, rather than performing the action. Your can update your code to use it like this: `Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf`

Comment: to reitterate i need a new 

Where {$_ -notlike "$UDir"} |   

line created for each $udir in $udirs

Comment: @NicTanghe - I think you need to clarify your problem statement. Exactly what are you trying to achieve, given example inputs and outputs. Spending more time guessing at a solution to the unclear question is unlikely to provide you the result you're _really_ after.

Answer (score 2):

So the `-like` and `-notlike` operators work on pattern matching e.g.

```
"gvee" -like    "*ve*" # Returns True
"gvee" -like    "*je*" # Returns False
"gvee" -notlike "*ve*" # Returns False
"gvee" -notlike "*je*" # Returns True
```

The comparitor works on *strings*. And an `array` is not a `string` but rather a collection of `string`s (subtle difference).

Assuming you're trying to get a list of user folders where the folder name is not in a list of strings; you don't actually need to use `-like` (as you're not pattern matching).

Instead you should is the `-in`/`-notin` operators!

```
$usersToKeep = "gvee", "Public", "etc"

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" |
    Where-Object Name -NotIn $usersToKeep
```

Comment: I think this wil stil delete the submaps.

Comment: No, this method does not allow wildcards. As for "the submaps" - if I have understood correctly you can switch the `-Recurse` option to `Remove-Item` as this method currently only returns the root folders for each user.

Comment: If my memory doesn't fail me this diden't work i wil test later today.

Comment: -Recurse is not a valid argument for remove item wich was the hole point of using this convoluted way in the first place.

Comment: @NicTanghe sorry bud, but `-Recurse` is most definitely a parameter of `Remove-Item`. Run this if you don't believe me: `Get-Help Remove-Item -Parameter Recurse`!

Comment: I can confirm this does not work.

I need to find a way to do a for each Piped object.
Where {$_ -notlike "$UDirs"}

Comment: PS H:\> $foldersToKeep = "test", "test2"

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test" |
    Where-Object Name -NotIn $foldersToKeep -recurse|

Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf

Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'recurse'.
At line:4 char:45
+     Where-Object Name -NotIn $foldersToKeep -recurse|
+                                             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: I can confirm this does not work. I need to find a way to do a for each Piped object. Where {$_ -notlike "$UDir"}  for each $udir in $udirs

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent answer by gvee that explains why `-like` and `-notlike` are not the correct operators to be using, and offering an alternative method. He answered first, you should really accept his answer. I'm just going to offer a little additional advise.

As a slight modification to his method I would like to suggest using `-Exclude` over using a `Where` statement, such as: (I also changed `$input` since that's a reserved variable)

```
#Get target computer name
$computer = (Read-Host "Enter Computer name")
#Create array of users to keep, include yourself by default
$UDirs = @('ntanghe')
do {
  $UserInput = (Read-Host "Enter Username")
  if ($UserInput -ne '') {$UDirs += $UserInput}
}
until ($UserInput -eq '')

$UDirs

GCI "\\$computer\c$\Users" -Directory -Exclude $UDirs | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

But rather than querying the target computer, getting all the data sent back over the network, then sending requests to delete those folders over the network to the target computer why not send one command to the target computer and have it do all the work without so much network chatter?

```
<stuff to get $computer and $UDirs>

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {GCI C:\Users -Directory -Exclude $using:UDirs|Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf} -ComputerName $computer
```

Then just remove the `-WhatIf` once you are satisfied that what would be deleted is the desired folders, and you're all set.

Lastly, you should make sure the target computer is online if possible.

```
Do{
    $computer = Read-Host "Enter target computer name"
}Until(Test-Connection $Computer -Quiet)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wont exclude the subdir's wich is why i'm trying this a different way in the first place.

Comment: Also I don't think i can work like that becouse the underlying comunication methot's are blocked by the firewall.

Also why whould you check if its of if it won't work when it is off anywhay.

Comment: After testing again i can confirm (again i already tested this and knew this)

That this does not work when more then 1 Directory is given to keep.

Comment: In my enviroment the methot you gave to reduce net trafic doesn't work.

And the exclude only works when only One directory is given.

As edited above.

I need a for each loop that checks for each piped thing.

Or i need to make a new pipe for each dir in " Where {$_ -notlike "$UDirs"}"

Comment: Exclude should work just fine with more than one directory. I tested it, and it worked on my end, and if you look at `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full` the parameter specifically states that it accepts an array of strings, not just a string.

Comment: Yes but are you testing it by feeding it with a pipe.

i'm not realy an expert but i think that is not an array but multiple one line statements.

Also i don't work there annymore so i cant test that out on their system annymore.